# Which account does your CodeCommit reside in a multi-account setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit, aws-organizations

I was reading on [organizing your AWS environment using multiple accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/organizing-your-aws-environment/organizing-your-aws-environment.html). On [this section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/organizing-your-aws-environment/deployments-ou.html), it is encouraged that pipelines should be on separate accounts mimicking production workloads.

That's pretty clear but where do you provision your CodeCommit that these pipelines and development accounts use? Should it be on the `management` account, these `cicd` accounts, or a separate account of its own?

Thank you in advance!